# how do i press tab keyboard to leave space instead of jumping to next button or section

Tags: email, casefeed

in normal text editor like notepad or word document, when I press tab keyboard key it will make a space for it but in Salesforce case feed email editor, when I press tab keyboard key it will jump to next section instead. how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not controlled by SalesForce. Its the browser that handles the tabbing. Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/67934/typing-the-tab-character-in-browser-text-boxes) for some possible solutions, such as using browser plugins.

Comment: i tried that but still jumping to next section..